# How to remove all pinned apps in windows 11 start menu using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I would like to create a powershell script that unpins all the app in the windows 11 start menu. I am reading this [article by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-start-menu-layout-windows-11) about the details on how to customize the start menu layout, but the method they mentioned is i have to use a MDM. I will be using the script for personal use only, there is no reason for me to pay (and an MDM seems to be overkill for just removing pinned apps).

I was wondering if there are some powershell pros out there who knows of a work around.

Here is my failed attempt:

Getting the app names that are pinned is mentioned in the article

> Export an existing Start layout
>
> 1. Create a folder to save the .json file. For example, create the
>    C:\Layouts folder.
> 2. On a Windows 11 device, open the Windows PowerShell app.
> 3. Run the following cmdlet. Name the file LayoutModification.json.
>
>    Export-StartLayout -Path "C:\Layouts\LayoutModification.json"

Here is the output for my pc

```
{"pinnedList":[
    {"desktopAppId":"Microsoft.Office.WINWORD.EXE.15"},
    {"desktopAppId":"Microsoft.Office.EXCEL.EXE.15"},
    {"desktopAppId":"Microsoft.Office.POWERPNT.EXE.15"},
    {"desktopAppId":"Chrome"}
  ]
}
```

and running this code i found with a bit modification, throws an error `Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?): 'Chrome'`. Maybe this is for windows 10 only, cant really say since i dont have a windows 10 machine to test

```
function Pin-App {    param(
        [string]$appname,
        [switch]$unpin
    )
    try{
        if ($unpin.IsPresent){
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'Von "Start" lösen|Unpin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' unpinned from Start"
        }else{
            ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace('&','') -match 'An "Start" anheften|Pin to Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
            return "App '$appname' pinned to Start"
        }
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error Pinning/Unpinning App! (App-Name correct?): '$appname' "
    }
}


Pin-App "Chrome" -unpin
```

I have a method that works that involves simulating keyboard presses. Specifically: `Windows button > Tab > right click (shift+F10) > Enter`. But this is prone to errors, because it only takes a key press or mouse click to break the chain an cause problems

Comment: This might be interesting: https://quake.blog/configure-windows-11-start-menu-using-only-group-policy.html

Comment: You're swallowing an exception with your ``try{} ... catch {}``` - what error message do you get it you remove it?

Comment: @zett42 This is great, and my only complaint about it is the need to relog-in. How does this work by the way? is the old layout still there and it is just not loaded?

Comment: @mclayton tried reducing the code a bit as you recommended, this line `((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{42.......` in the unpin case throws an error `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Comment: Ok, so something in your expression is evaluating to ```$null``` but it's hard to guess which part - you might need to break your one-liner down into multiple steps and do some null checking before you call each step. That will at least tell you which part is evaluating to ```$null```, and will help narrow down the search for a solution...

Comment: @mclayton Found it, `((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq $appname}).Verbs() ` specificallyy the `.Verbs()` call . I have no idea what to replace it with though as i have no idea what it does...

Comment: If the call to ```.Verbs()``` is failing it means ```| ?{$_.Name -eq $appname})``` is returning ```$null``` - i.e. there's no entries called ```$appname``` in the result set returned by the prior call to ```.Items()```. Try something like ```$items = ((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items(); write-host ($items.Name | fl | out-string)``` to see a list of the app names in the collection and check the one you're trying to remove is actually present...

Comment: @mclayton i can only guess that it looks for the app name in the item list, but when i check the names in the item list chrome is not in there, and so does the other pinned apps, i think the location of the items might be wrong, if thats the case this might be a dead end unless somone know where to get the correct list

Comment: This may be of help to you https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-1909-why-are-pin-to-starttaskbar-verbs/72194716-9d24-4bdd-bb51-3f7f5ae64047